# How to maintain check box in recycler view position for different fragment in android

Tags: android

I have a recycler view with check box in the each fragment in android 
. I want to check single Check box all the other check boxes when i clicks on a particular check box in the view it get select the first position in all fragment.how  can i maintain those position.

Comment: save checkbox position in any global variable or shared preference then on fragment change take that position and check your heck box in all fragments

Comment: Did not really understand your question. You can add the code you've tried till now and maybe add an image representation of what you want to achieve, that way we can help you out.